# ID for Feature in GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, geotools, specification

The geotools library's GeoJSON plugin requires an ID to generate a Feature type. The specification of GeoJSON says it is a SHOULD and not a must. I'm trying to get rows from a database like SQL Server or Postgres and convert it to GeoJSON. Should I make the ID to the primary key of the table or I should let generate the ID by the library?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is your choice. I have generated GeoJSON without an ID for a simple map in Leaflet and never had a problem. I've used the database primary key when I'm updating attributes and want to post back to as SQL Update. I've also used a name field that I knew was unique so I could tie it to a jQuery Autocomplete widget for searching and selecting my polygons. I've also had the ID field use my ID field that I later found was blank and useless with no harm to may app. In my case The ID field was an integer and once a string.

I think it's really what you want it to be and how you program against it in your app.